# Is there a way to securely check in sensitive variables into git?

Tags: git, .env

I have a bunch of variables in a .env file locally with all of my applications configuration, lets say this configuration works, as of a particular commit.

.dockerignore and .gitignore files are used to exclude this file from commits and builds.

Basically, if something goes wrong, I want to be able to revert back to a previous commit and the .env file at the time of that commit.

Is there a secure, efficient and seamless way to do this?

Comment: If you don't version-control the .env file, you won't have information about which commit it has been changed in. However, you could try encrypting the file with some secret key and check in the encrypted version.

Comment: Why would you store secrets in an environment file you would have to version? Wouldn't you normally only store things which aren't versioned in such a file?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You don't want to include the .env file in your repo but at the same time you want to be able to access it when you revert commits?

Comment: I also don't really understand your request and not tracking secrets is often the best solution but maybe you will be interested by git-crypt: https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

Comment: You can make a parallel git repository `.git-env` in the same working tree and commit to that. Just be careful to not delete it with a `git clean` (not that I have ever done that); protect it by ignoring it in `.gitignore`.